# Segment Fault On any file access C/SDL2

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, sdl-2

I can not figure out why this program is Segment faulting when ever I run this function:
https://github.com/biohazard-hack/high-hand/blob/master/events.c#L73

I have another version of this program that was a rough draft and that is here:
http://pastebin.com/TgiqM9tX

I understand that how I am reading the file in the current version is wrong but it segment faults when I use fscanf() or anything to access the file.

It will open the file in text or binary read mod just fine but the second I do any type of reading from it, it blows up.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tracer/code/rcg/high-hand/high-hand 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
INFO: Hand is not NULL

This is the  output using fscanf() from gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7537686 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=s@entry=0x9ee820, 
    format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc78, 
    errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:843
843 vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please at least fire up debugger; you wouldn't go far without solving your mistakes yourself.

Problem isn't caused by code in question. In `main.h` there is `extern char* Curl[5];`, but in `main.c` it is initialised with:

```
char*           Curl[5] ={  "img/cards/rj.png",
                            "img/cards/rj.png",
                            "img/cards/rj.png",
                            "img/cards/rj.png",
                            "img/cards/rj.png"
};
```

String constants are placed in constant memory and are not allowed to be modified. When you're trying to change this strings, you get segfault because you're attempting to write to read-only pages.

Probably simplest solution is changing type to e.g. `char Curl[5][32]` (make sure size is enough to hold file name) in both places.

As a side note, your heavy overuse of global variables is asking for problems to happen, and `foo()` is not how function that takes no arguments is defined in C (but it is in C++ though).

Comment: Thank you, I know the global variables are an issue here, just getting a feel for where to put them and where I end up using them. otherwise I end up passing way to many values to endless locations.